# gunzip in a bash script with full path

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script where I download a tar file and then I untar it as

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"
tar -xvf $SCRIPT_DIR/my_file.tar
rm -f $SCRIPT_DIR/my_file.tar
gunzip LAL*
```

ok, it works. **But**, if I specify the full path to `gunzip`, as one may expect naturally, i.e., `gunzip $SCRIPT_DIR/LAL*`, the unzipped files do not appear and the program crashes in a further step.

I find this odd. I solved it creating in the beginning of the script `cd "${0%/*}"` :

```
cd "${0%/*}"
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"
tar -xvf $SCRIPT_DIR/my_file.tar
rm -f $SCRIPT_DIR/my_file.tar
gunzip $SCRIPT_DIR/LAL*
```

But I think this get me even more confused than before. What is happening and what should I do? Thx. (The cd... and the SCRIPT_DIR... lines were taken from SO).

Comment: If you're being so careful in your script's first line about being able to handle directory names with spaces, why throw all that caution out the window in later lines? Make sure you have double quotes around every `$SCRIPT_DIR` to prevent it from being split into multiple words on spaces in IFS.

Comment: (Also, all-caps variable names are in space that the POSIX standard specifies for use by variables that are meaningful to the shell itself; it would be better for `script_dir` to be lowercase -- this is specified because it's safe for a script to define its own `path` variable with arbitrary contents, but not to assign an arbitrary `PATH` variable; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that environment and shell variables share a single namespace -- setting a shell variable overwrites a like-named environment variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting from a tar file puts the files in the current directory (and subdirectories of the current directory), not the directory containing the archive.

So even though the tar file is in `$SCRIPT_DIR`, the extracted files won't be. They'll be in the current directory.

You can use the `-C` option to `tar` to tell it to change to a different directory when extracting.

```
tar -xvf "$SCRIPT_DIR/my_file.tar" -C "$SCRIPT_DIR"
```

Comment: I'm afraid the -C option didn't solve it. With -C in the tar, both `gunzip full_path/LAL*` and `gunzip LAL*` do not work. Script only works if I specify the line `cd "${0%/*}"`.

Comment: Ok, I now see my mistake. Being my script at cron, essentially I needed to do a `cd $SCRIPT_DIR` at the beginning. Thank you, I accept the asnwer.